# Using Rails Path and URL Helpers with fast_jsonapi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, fastjsonapi

I would like to use the rails URL helper instead of hard coding the path to access the article.

I checked into the [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#links-per-object) but nothing is specified.

The `article_path` helper method exists (I checked by running `rake routes`)

```
class V3::ArticlesController < Api::V3::BaseController
  def index
    articles = Article.all
    render json: ::V3::ArticleItemSerializer.new(articles).serialized_json
  end
end

class V3::ArticleItemSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :title

  link :working_url do |object|
    "http://article.com/#{object.title}"
  end

  # link :what_i_want_url do |object|
  #   article_path(object)
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [max's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064028/2679301).

I also changed the gem to `jsonapi-serializer`

```
class V3::ArticlesController < Api::V3::BaseController
  def index
    articles = Article.all
    render json: ::V3::ArticleItemSerializer.new(articles, params: { context: self }).serialized_json
  end
end

class V3::ArticleItemSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :title

  link :working_url do |object|
    "http://article.com/#{object.title}"
  end

  link :also_working_url do |object, params|
    params[:context].article_path(object)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is pass in the context to your serializer from your controller:

```
module ContextAware
  def initialize(resource, options = {})
    super
    @context = options[:context]
  end
end
```

```
class V3::ArticleItemSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  include ContextAware
  attributes :title

  link :working_url do |object|
    @context.article_path(object)
  end
end
```

```
class V3::ArticlesController < Api::V3::BaseController
  def index
    articles = Article.all
    render json: ::V3::ArticleItemSerializer.new(articles, context: self).serialized_json
  end
end
```

You should also switch to the [jsonapi-serializer gem](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) which is currently maintained as fast_jsonapi was abandoned by Netflix.

Comment: Also note that you should always explicitly nest modules and classes to avoid suprising constant lookups. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: It didn't work with the ContextAware module, maybe because I created it into the app/serializers folder? I posted another solution

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Not sure exactly what's going wrong as I didn't actually test it and wrote it more as a conceptual answer.